# Two divs on each other animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, slider

I just want to create the animation like in this website http://www.msambition.de/. I have created 2 divs 1 on other. I have jquery code as below:
$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('div.unternehmen-ahover').hover(

function () {
    $('div.unternehmen-ahover').slideToggle("slow");
    $('span.span-picture-menu').fadeIn();
},

function () {

});
$('div.unternehmen').hover(

function () {

},

function () {
    $('div.unternehmen-ahover').slideToggle("slow");
    $('span.span-picture-menu').fadeOut();
});
});
```

Te problem is that on hver it works fine but it remains on other div sometimes and does not do slidetoggle. Kindly help me in this regards.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create mouseenter and mouseleave event handler for your div and there you should slideToggle. See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/D4Ah3/2/).

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{    
    $(".tile2").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".trainingmood").delay(0).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300, "");
        $(".text2 span").delay(100).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300, "");
        $(".text2").animate({ marginLeft: "-=310px" }, 300);
    });

    $(".tile2").mouseleave(function () {

        $(".trainingmood").delay(0).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300, "");
        $(".text2 span").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3, 00, "");
        $(".text2").animate({ marginLeft: "+=310px" }, 300);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That just solved my problem. I am feeling lucky. Just a little thing how I do the text sliding not from left but from top to bottom.

Comment: Only the text or div.trainingmood also?

Comment: Are they both moving? Or only text is moving? If text is moving alone then text. If both are mving then both. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Catch the answer by this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/D4Ah3/3/). :) I hope it will what you asked :) And if you can just update your profile. Add nick name at last.

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you a lot. I needed just as it is now. I have added my name also. Thank again :)